# how is the NinjectDependencyResolver hooked in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have integrated Ninject into an MVC 4 project using the Nuget `Ninject.MVC3` package. I can see that `App_Start` now contains a class called `NinjectWebCommon`, with a 'bootstrapper'. Following the standard instructions I can inject a concrete instance of an interface into a controller, and the debugger shows me that this is being served up by the `NinjectDependencyResolver` class.

However: I can't find out, by poking into the Ninject code, where this `NinjectDependencyResolver` class is being set as the `IDependencyResolver` using the standard `DependencyResolver.SetResolver` method. So I'm not sure if I'm just being inept, or whether there's an alternative way this is getting hooked in. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDependencyResolver` ships with asp.net MVC framework and allows implementing dependency injection into controllers and other components (asp.net MVC use it internaly) .

I won't explain benefits here but you can read a good introduction [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html).

When adding an IoC framework (Ninject, Unity, StructureMap, ...) into MVC, you have to plug the Ioc code to the native dependency resolver, with an implementation of `IDependencyResolver`.
The DependencyResolver static class is the registration point, especially `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(IDependencyResolver resolver)`

But now, many Ioc framework come with an MVC integration package such as Ninject.MVC our StructureMap.MVC. It's easier for us (and often more robust) and you don't really need to known how it is done.

A quick look at [NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin.cs) in repositoty [Ninject.Web.Mvc](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/) will show you the glue.

Comment: Thanks... so how does NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin get hooked in then?

Comment: it's a Ninject Plugin that is added to the main Ninject MVC module https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/MvcModule.cs

Comment: Thanks - I see now, it's added in the following lines: IEnumerable<INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin> all = Bootstrapper.kernelInstance.Components.GetAll<INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin>();
all.Map<INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin>((INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin c) => c.Start());